# How to filter data in a DBGrid with a ComboBox in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7, dbgrid

How do you filter data in a DBGrid with a ComboBox?

For example, if the ComboBox text is "table 1", the DBGrid shows table 1.

[image]

This is the code that I tried:

```pascal
procedure TForm4.cbb2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cbb2.Text = 'Surat Masuk Edaran' then
    with DataModule1.zqry_srt_masuk_edaran do
    begin
      dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet := 'ds_srt_masuk_edaran'
    end else

    if cbb2.Text = 'Surat Masuk Undangan' then
      with DataModule1.zqry_srt_masuk_undangan do
      begin
        dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet := 'ds_srt_masuk_undangan'
      end else

      if cbb2.Text = 'Surat Masuk Lain-lain' then
        with DataModule1.zqry_srt_masuk_lain2 do
        begin
          dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet := 'ds_srt_masuk_lain2'
        end;
end;
```

Comment: The `DataSource.DataSet` property is not a `string`, it is a pointer to a `TDataSet`-derived component. I would suggest storing the DataSets into an array that mirrors the ComboBox, and then use the ComboBox's selected `ItemIndex` as an index onto that array. That will greatly simply your `OnChange` code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't filter the DBGrid itself, you filter the data provided by its assigned `DataSource`.

For example, set the DBGrid's `DataSource` property to a `TDataSource` component, and set the DataSource's `DataSet` property to a `TTable` component. Configure the `TTable` as needed to access your DB. When the user selects a table in the ComboBox, set the `TTable.TableName` property accordingly.

Comment: is that mean I only need to use one datasource?

Comment: @RidhoIkhsani you could, but if you have multiple DataSets, it makes sense to have a separate DataSource for each DataSet. Then you can swap around the `DataSource`s in the DBGrid as needed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [`Items`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomCombo.Items) contains the table names. So you can directly use:

```
procedure TForm4.cbb2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataModule.Table.Close;
  DataModule.Table.TableName:= TComboBox(Sender).Text;
  DataModule.Table.Open;
end;
```

If that's not the case, then you can use an `Array` of `String` as

```
Const
MyArray: array [0..CntTables] of string = ('Table1','Table2','Table3');
```

And use it as

```
procedure TForm4.cbb2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataModule.Table.Close;
  DataModule.Table.TableName:= MyArray[TComboBox(Sender).ItemIndex];
  DataModule.Table.Open;
end;
```